# Netbeans and SVN Reverting code back

Tags: java, svn, netbeans, collabnet

I am using netbeans alongside Collabnet SVN, i am going to commit large numbers of code changes to the svn but i am a bit concerned about reverting the code back, the project consists of several packages in which each file in those packages have different version numbers, how i see it is if i want to revert code back i will have to revert each file manually one by one.

I essentially want to create a large revision snapshot of the code before i submit everything so i can easily revert code back with a single revert. I am fairly new to using svn so not sure if this is possible? If so can someone point me in the right direction how i would go about doing this.

Thanks

Comment: if you are using SVN then you dont need to worry , simply commit the code , you can revert back to any version any time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm probably just going to use tagging/branching to create a another version in my SVN and switch to that version if i need to.

Answer (score 0):

By default SVN commits a set of files/directory together - if you say commit on the top level directory. So, assuming you modified 10 files, one commit will contain all the changes, allowing an easy revert. In theory you could commit "file by file", but does not seem to be what you want anyhow.

From your question I understand you have only one SVN repository ("to the svn").

Comment: Yes i have only have one repository, one of the issue i have is one of my  directory(package) has a revision number of 804 whilst one file in the directory(package) has a revision number of 806(previous revision number was 775), Now if i revert the package what revision number will the file go back to 806 or 775?

Comment: "revert" means reverting back to the last committed revision downloaded from the server. So, if the file had version 806, you modify (but don't commit) and say revert, it will go back to 806. If for example somebody committed 807, but you do not do "update", the revert will still revert to 806.